# How to use Google translate button for conversion to specific language only?

Tags: google-translate, translate

Here's the code from https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

But the situation I have is, that user enters text in a textbox in English, hit 'Translate' button and the other text box get translated text in Spanish.
I tried replacing 'google_translate_element' to 'es' or 'Spanish' but did not work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution from google support, so sharing for someone who might need it. You may use includedLanguages and list comma separated languages which you want to display in dropdown :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'es', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE, autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element');
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>

</body>
</html>
```